# Why isn't whitespace recognised by the unix core utils in my script?

Tags: grep, curl, cut

I'm writing a short script to pull the price of bitcoin. The information will be piped into an i3block so that I can see the hourly price on my status bar - here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
price=$(curl -s gbp.rate.sx/btc?T | tail -3 | head -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*' | cut -d ' ' -f1)
echo $price
```

I curl the bitcoin price (in £) from [rate.sx](https://github.com/chubin/rate.sx) with the T option (text only, no ANSI sequences), select the average price line using head and tail and grep out the numbers. The output looks something like this:

```
26563 26396 1738 8 6 29
```

The first number is the average price, with the others being the median, change, etc...
As you can see, I pass this through cut with whitespace as the delimiter, but the output is uncut.

I also tried to swap whitespace for ',' to try convert the output to csv, but this failed also.

```
price=$(curl -s gbp.rate.sx/btc?T | tail -3 | head -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*' | sed 's/ /,/' )
```

The above also gave me the same output. Why are `cut` and `sed` struggling to recognise the whitespace?

Comment: If you execute `curl -s gbp.rate.sx/btc?T | tail -3 | head -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*'` you will notice that `grep -o '[0-9]*'` outputs each matching sequence of digits on a separate *line*

Comment: Are you just looking for the average price? (You don't actually say what output you want from your example.) If so, just use `curl … | LC_ALL=C grep -Po '^avg:.*?\K[[0-9]+'` I can explain this if it really does match what you want.

Comment: Thank you, turned out the spaces were actually newlines! Fixed with:
`price=$(curl -s gbp.rate.sx/btc?T | tail -3 | head -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*' | cut -d$'\n' -f1)`

Comment: @crystal_pepsi Isn't that `cut` command in your last comment just the same as `head -1` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're having with your own pipeline is that you don't realize that the output from `grep` is several *lines* long, with one integer on each line. The numbers are outputted on the same line only because you use `$price` unquoted.

---

If you want the average price, i.e. the amount after the `avg:` tag, then it would be easiest with `awk`:

```bsh
curl -s 'https://gbp.rate.sx/btc?T' |
awk '/^avg:/ { print $2 }'
```

What the `awk` code above is doing is to print the second whitespace-delimited field from each line that starts with the text `avg:`.

This would give you something like `£26421`.  Would you want that amount without the pound symbol, use `print substr($2,2)` in place of `print $2`.

Would you want to do this using `grep` and `cut` instead, then do something like

```bsh
curl -s 'https://gbp.rate.sx/btc?T' |
grep '^avg:' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

To delete the pound symbol from this, just pipe this through either `cut -c 2-` or `tr -d '£'` at the end.

Note that to just output the result of this, there is no reason to first put it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks, I should say that the only reason I have this as a variable is because occasionally i3blocks messes up with these sort of scripts. I wrote a very similar script curling wttr.in weather info to a block and the block simply would not work unless I echo'd the output as a variable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

> The output looks something like this:
>
> ```
> echo $price
> 26563 26396 1738 8 6 29
> ```

That's because `$price` is unquoted, which makes the shell split it on whitespace. `echo` gets multiple arguments, which it joins with single spaces.

See e.g.: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)